# How can I use import, from import and sys.append together in Python

Tags: python, module

I have a directory I add to sys.path to import custom modules. What is the correct/best way to use import, from import and sys.path together? What I mean is if it acceptable to use sys.path.append in between the "imports".

For example:

```
#!C:/Python27
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\user\\myPythonModules')
import writedata as wd
import os
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
```

**Edit:**

I should have mentioned that `writedata` would be a custom module that I want to import as `wd`. The module `writedata` is located in `C:\\Users\\user\\myPythonModules`

Comment: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Comment: You can use `import` statements anywhere you like, but it's [best practice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) to put them all together at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. There is no syntax or semantic rule in the language that prevents that.

I am not aware of any "style" rule that you may be breaking, but in any case, another option is providing [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to the python interpreter.

Comment: The broken style rule is [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: It doesn't specifically say anything about extending ``sys.path`` in between the "imports section", but I guess it is something to avoid in favor of correctly setting up ``sys.path`` prior to script execution.

Comment: @jvdm how would i setup sys.path prior to script execution? I use `if __name__ == '__main__':main()` to kick off main() which does the rest..

Comment: It specifically says that all the imports should be at the top. Putting a reference reassignment in the middle of them means that the following `import`s are in the middle of the code rather than at the top.

Comment: @jes516 AFAIK, put ``PYTHONPATH`` in your environment, I'm not aware of any other options.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 She/He requires ``sys.path`` extended prior to the import statement to import "custom modules", PEP doesn't address that case, so it would be a compromise.

Comment: @jvdm that is what i want to understand. all of the how to make your own modules i've seen online recommend to put all custom modules in their own directory and then add that path to sys.path. but can i do this without breaking pep8?